# Docker Compose doesn´t work when adding Logging Option

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

We discovered that some of our containers write so much logging messages that it will be a problem in the future, if we don`t limit the size. I found this [article](https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/rotating-docker-logs-keeping-your-overlay-folder-small-40cfa2155412) which seems to be the perfect solution to our problem.

So I took this docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:1.0.4
    container_name: rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - mysql-designer-rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
    environment:
      - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user"
      - "RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pw"
    ports:
      - "15674:15674"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "1883:1883"
    restart: unless-stopped
  mysql:
    image: mysql:1.0.5
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql-designer-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=db"
      - "MYSQL_USER=user"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=pw"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  sitestructure:
    image: sitestructure:319
    container_name: sitestructure
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/sitestructure/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbit
    links:
      - mysql
      - rabbit
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 10
```

and edited the sitestructure container and put these lines to it:

```
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        max-file: 5
        max-size: 10m
```

Now when I try to update the containers the Command Line just says

```
Recreating sitestructure ...
```

And this seems to never end. Only if I remove the lines from the compose file I can use it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. But not per container but for all containers at the same time. I edited my daemon.json file and added

```
"log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m", 
    "max-file": "3"
  }
```

After a restart and removing and adding all containers it now works.